# When would I prefer to use json over a query-string?

Tags: json, http, query-string

I stumbled upon a question which I can not find answer to in the internet: when would I prefer to use a JSON and when would I prefer to use a query-string?

would very much appreciate any further thoughts of yours experts on the topic.

Coded examples would be very much appreciated as well

Thanks!

Comment: query strings have limited length and json is better for holding complex data. JSON is typical for posts while query strings would be more typical for a simple get

Comment: Your question isn't really clear (query strings and JSON are orthogonal features of a data format, not alternatives to each other), assuming you meant the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format, then it depends (because there are extended versions of that which have some of the benefits of JSON), is (to a significant degree) opinion based, and is too broad (given the various variations of the data formats).

Comment: thanks @chevybow that make sense

Comment: @Quentin. I guess I don't really got the idea behind your answer. Could you please elaborate a little further?

Comment: @guyr79 — It's not an answer. It is a comment, pointing out that your question doesn't really make sense (for three different reasons).

Comment: See [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced." and "Don't ask about... Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc." (You are asking for a list of situations)

Comment: @Quentin, Thank you  for the link. I was not aware there are questions that should not be asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make things straight:

1. Query string is a fragment of URL that is after `?` mark. For example in `http://test.com/foo?baz=1` the fragment `baz=1` is the query string for that URL.
2. JSON is a well known data format. I won't dig here into the spec (since it is quite well known), but for example `{"test":1}` is a JSON string.

And so these are two different things. It is not like "this or that", for example you can combine both to have

```
http://test.com/?{"test":1}
```

And now you have JSON as a query string. Note that query string format is not standardized so this is completely valid.

So as you can see these two are not really comparable. Unless by "query string" you actually mean the concrete format, i.e. the typical `x=1&y=2&z=3` style. These two we can compare. JSON has advantage of better structure, you can nest objects, you have arrays, you have (few but still) types. But it is less readable, especially since some characters in URL have to be escaped. And it takes a bit more time to parse it (unlikely to matter though).

My approach is as follows: for `GET` use "standard" query strings in URL, for `POST` JSON in body. If your `GET` becomes more complicated then turn it into a `POST` with JSON.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer! very much appreciated!